# Proving that powers of 2 are not bounded above

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $2^k > n$. (This is part of my solution to proving that the set of all rational numbers $p/q$, with $q$ a power of $2$, is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.)

Proof: Assume not. Then there is some $n_0 > 2^k$ for all $k$. I want to say that this implies the existence of a greatest element in the set of all powers of $2$—call it $2^{k_0}$—but then $2^{k_0 + 1}$ would be a power of $2$ greater than that. Contradiction.

Is this a valid proof? If some subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is bounded above by some $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$, is there a greatest element in that subset? Why? I know that any nonempty subset of $\mathbb{N}$ has a least element by the well-ordering property, but I've never heard anything about greatest elements.

Comment: doesn't $n=2^k+1$ do the trick?

Comment: @CarryonSmiling I don't think so. n is given so you would have to use $ k = alog (n) +1$ which then needs the properties of logarithms in the proof.

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad.

Comment: you can prove $2^n>n$ with induction then :)

Comment: If some subset of $\mathbb N$ is bounded above then yes, it has a greatest element (can you prove it ?) . And then your proof by contradiction works.

Comment: $\mathbb N$ is a totally ordered set, and if a subset $M \subset \mathbb N$ is bounded above by $m$ then it has at most $m$ elements and in particular it is finite. A finite totally ordered set which is bounded above has a greatest element.

Comment: Why is your last statement true? (that a finite totally ordered set which is bounded above has a greatest element)

Comment: Because in a finite number of steps we can order (sequence) them and the last one is the greatest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can take $k=n$. We just have to prove $2^n>n$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$.

We can do this with induction.

First prove it for $n=1$ it is easy: $2^1=2>1$.

Now, suppose it is true for $n\geq 1$. So we have $2^n>n$. Because of this we have $2(2^n)>2n$, so $2^{n+1}>2n=n+n\geq n+1$ as we needed.

Comment: Yes, that works.

Comment: This is a great help. I was wondering if you could also speak to my last paragraph about greatest elements?

Comment: Yes, what you say is true. Suppose the set $A\subseteq \mathbb N$ is bounded above by $M$. Consider the set of positive integers $A'=\{M-a+1 | a \in A\}$. This set has a least element. Therefore there exists $m\in A$ so that $M-m+1\leq M-a+1$ for all $a\in A$. Notice $M-m+1\leq M-a+1\implies -m\leq -a\implies m\geq a$. So $m$ is the maximum for $A$ we were looking for.

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I was looking for. Very clear how fundamental the well ordering property is.